# Variable in javascript command

Tags: javascript

I have this `javascript` command, which works fine:

```
return top.GO.tasks.showTaskDialog({tasklist_id:907});
```

However I would like to insert a `variable` called *id* instead of "907".

I have tried

```
return top.GO.tasks.showTaskDialog({tasklist_id: + id + });
```

but that does not work..

Thanks for all help!

Comment: `return top.GO.tasks.showTaskDialog({tasklist_id: id }); ` no need the +s because its not a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `id` variable already exists:

```
return top.GO.tasks.showTaskDialog({tasklist_id: id});
```

`{tasklist_id: id}` represents an `object` that has a property called `tasklist_id` whom `value` is the one contained by the `id` variable.

Comment: Thanks Erazihel. Works exactly as I wanted.